# More efficient way script the heights of DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using this script to find the height of a DIV. I am using it on more than one DIV. 
Is there a more efficient way to write this code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".block00").height($(".subheader").height());
    $(".block01").height($(".subheader").height()); 
    $(".block02").height($(".subheader").height());
});
```

Comment: Can't you use elem.offsetHeight?

Comment: it depends entirely on your markup. Post the relevant html.

Answer (score 2):

No need to list each one separately or make a loop as you can just list multiple items in the selector and it will return all of them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".block00, .block01, .block02").height($(".subheader").height());
});
```

or a little more efficiently:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var h = $(".subheader").height();
    $(".block00, .block01, .block02").height(h);
});
```

or, if you control the HTML source, add a common class on all the blockXX objects so you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var h = $(".subheader").height();
    $(".blockCommon").height(h);
});
```

Remember, you can have more than one class per object.  Using a common class among several objects is precisely for the situation where you want to treat a number of objects the same way.

Comment: Thansk very much. Getting my head around this. I am using for animation of sites. Not easy though but very rewarding. Again thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var h=$(".subheader").height();
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++)$(".block0"+i)height(h.height());
});
```

might work

Comment: The for loop actually makes this code run less efficiently than without. It's better to unroll the loop. It will be (marginally) faster and easier to understand.

Comment: I don't know much about jQuery, but I guess it will do the same thing when calling $(".block00, .block01, .block02").height(h); I think it will iterate through the set .block00, .block01, .block02 ..